# Is it correct to say 'two/three parter movie'?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I have been wondering about this for sometime now.

I often hear people say two-parter. Is it correct/formal?

I want to describe a documentary movies consisting of three parts. Three-parter movie? How about a trilogy?

Comment: One note about the answers below: to my ear, "this movie is a three-parter" sounds fine, but "this is a three-parter movie" doesn't. "Three-parter", in this context, works well as a noun, and using it as an adjective sounds wrong (again, to me).

Comment: In "This is a (...) movie" where's the need for *er*? "This is a **three-part** movie" should do?

Comment: Three-part movie and trilogy are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely informal.  More formal would be, "*This is a three-part documentary*," or "*This week, we'll be airing a documentary, in three parts*."

This follows general hyphenation rule #1, as shown at [this website](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/1/).

"*My documentary is a three-parter*" might be deemed acceptable as informal speech.  ("Parter" is defined in a few dictionaries as "one who parts" - and it's even being flagged by my spell checker as I type this - so using it to describe a trilogy would be inappropriate, except in the case of informal slang).

*Trilogy* is defined as "a series of three dramatic or literary works."  I suppose you could use it to describe a documentary, although the word usually connotes a fictional work, such as *Lord of the Rings*, at least in my mind.

Comment: **No, *The Lord of the Rings* is not a trilogy!**  It is a single story. It has historically been published in one, three, and seven parts, but this is merely an accident of publishing and bookbinding. The story remains unitary.In contrast, Alexander Dumas’s ***D’Artagnan Romances*** were a trilogy comprising
*The Three Musketeers, Twenty Years After,* and *The Vicomte de Bragelonne.*
So too were Steven Brust’s tripartite ***Khaavren Romances***: *The Phoenix Guards, Five
Hundred Years After,* and *The Viscount of Adrilankha.* And yes, the latter trilogy is a sort of homage to the former.

Comment: Can you clarify your last sentence? Lord of the Rings is not a non-fiction work.

Comment: @Roronoa Zoro: Sorry, I meant _fictional_ work; I've edited my post to correct my error.

Comment: @tchrist: Perhaps _The Lord of the Rings_ is a single story, but its film adaptation was put into 3 parts, so I'd still call it a trilogy.  (Egads! for the love of Frodo, I don't want to debate this!  I'm not alone; apparently, the [Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trilogy?view=uk) thinks _Lord of the Rings_ is a great example for the word "_trilogy_." Other sites, such as [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Lord-Rings-Picture-Trilogy-Extended/dp/B000654ZK0), and even [LOTR.net](http://www.lordoftherings.net/) don't have a problem with the _trilogy_ label, either.)

Comment: @J.R. It was Professor Tolkien himself, not merely the author of the work in question but also the one-time sub-editor of the OED (which you did ***not*** cite), who insisted that *The Lord of the Rings* was “of course *not* a trilogy”. **Far be it from me** to disregard both his wishes and his learning in this particular matter in favor of general mass ignorance. It is a matter of ***sensitivity, reason, and respect*** to conform to his preferred usage about his own work — but if you choose to disregard all three, do as thou wilt. A trilogy cannot be one story; it must by definition be three.

Comment: Who says I was referring to Tolkien's original work?  The O.P. asked about movies, not books.  I merely asserted that *trilogy* normally connotes fiction, at least in my mind, and might therefore not be a good fit for a documentary.  Moreover, a trilogy is "any series or group of three related dramatic or other literary works," (OED, meaning #2), so Peter Jackson's film series would certainly apply. But thanks for the interesting history about Tolkien's sentiments.

Answer (score 0):

If you often hear people say it, then it must be part of the language. If we can call a bus a double-decker, then there seems to be no reason why we can't call a film a two-parter. Most discussions of films are likely to be in an informal context anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Two-parter:

1) may denote something "having two parts"

2) may imply  "a situation that is uncharacteristically complicated, that takes a 
long time or a large amount of effort to resolve" [Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Two-parter&defid=5868482).

In both case, usage is informal.